# styling an hover element css hanging together

Tags: html, css, hover, positioning

Hey i am trying to style a element, but i really need you help again!
http://codepen.io/jacobgDK/pen/tGeDF - style/span need

Thanks!

The html is:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="/index.php"><div> >> Restauranten << </div></a></li> <!-- dispalyed as active -->
        <li><a href="/menuer.php"><div class="span"> >> </div>Menuen<div class="span"> << </div></a></li>
        <li><a href="/indtryk.php"><div class="span"> >> </div>Indtryk<div class="span"> << </div</a>></li>
        <li><a href="/kontakt.php"><div class="span"> >> </div>Kontakt<div class="span"> << </div></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The css is here too:

http://codepen.io/jacobgDK/pen/tGeDF

Please give a hint were i am stuck or how to complete it, i cant wait to learn it now after trying 7 hours. :§

Comment: Why are you using <div class="span"> instead of <span>?

Comment: Would recommend escaping the less than and greater than symbols as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hjv6cyn/
Here I use the `before` and `after` selector.